# Application doesn't play music when transferred to phone

Tags: android

I created an app that plays the song in the background when it starts, and it works fine when I do it in Eclipse, but once I transferred the app to my phone the song no longer plays?

Any proposed suggestions/solutions as to what I should do?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you playing song that is stored on the device? or are you streaming it online?

Answer (score 0):

Throwing out the simple things. Have you verified volume is all the way up and that the music file was also successfully transferred to the device? Is the music file located at the path where the program expects it to be? Can you connect the device and use the debug tool to step through the application while running on the device?

Comment: Yes to all of those, but I made another simple mistake that I realized and fixed. Thank you!